# Multiple Gather tags under the same parent Response tag

Tags: python, api, twilio, ivr

Continuing 
[the question I had raised before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122561/unable-to-redirect-to-method-url-through-action-prop-in-gather-method-twilio), I am stuck with another issue. I have spent a good amount of time trying various combinations to fix the problem, but I came up with none.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Hello Monkey</Say>
    <Gather action="/user-A-input" method="POST">
        <Say>Please press the input A.</Say>
    </Gather>
    <Gather action="/user-B-input" method="POST">
        <Say>Please press the input B.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

However, when I try to enter the input A, it immediately hangs up after that and the input B gather section is not executed. There is no documentation of anyone else who is working with around this same logic as far as I have searched.

This is how the user-A-input and user-B-input looks like in Route.py of my code:

```
@app.route("/user-A-input", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def UserAInput():
    """Handle key press from a user."""
    # Get the digit pressed by the user
    #The below logs are not printed, so somehow this method isn't called
    logger.debug('before considering user input A')
    strA = request.values.get('Digits', None)
    logger.debug('In side A| A:' + strA)
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    return str(resp) #Something feels wrong here

@app.route("/user-B-input", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def UserBInput():
    """Handle key press from a user."""
    # Get the digit pressed by the user
    #The below logs are not printed, so somehow this method isn't called
    logger.debug('before considering user input B')
    strB = request.values.get('Digits', None)
    logger.debug('In side B| B:' + strB)
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    return str(resp) #Something feels wrong here
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me understand what is it that I am actually messing up here. Probably it has something to do with the return, but I am not sure. Or probably a workaround to the problem. I plan to use input A and B and make an API call to get the data and say it back to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't come up with an ethical and correct solution, I still figured a way to fix the issue by putting the logic of user-A-input, user-B-input and the API call request (the one for which I needed A and B input) in the user-A-input method. At the end of the receiving input A, I redirected the call to the main method ("/"), which in turn called user-A-input again, but with some flags that helped me skip the input A part and get directly into the input B part, I made sure I was recording it in the right variables, and then passing the input A and B to the other API to get the response. It might all sound a little vague and complicated, but you would surely understand if you check [my git repo](https://github.com/afsangujarati93/TranslinkApiIntegration). I wished if there was a better solution to this.

Comment: I'm glad you've got this working, but using global variables like that will break if more than one person calls the application at the same time as they will be set wrong for the second person. If you want to pass the result of the first `<Gather>` through to the second, I recommend you add the result to the URL as a query parameter.

Comment: Yeah! Didn't think about that. Will make changes for that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't use two [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) tags in the same response. However you can achieve the result you want with a couple of changes.

Let me explain what happens first. When Twilio reaches a `<Gather>` in some TwiML it waits to collect the responses from the user and then submits the responses to the `action` URL and directs the call onto that URL too. Nothing after a `<Gather>` in one action will get seen.

The thing to do is return your second `<Gather>` from your `/user-A-input`.

Something like this:

First TwiML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Hello Monkey</Say>
    <Gather action="/user-A-input" method="POST">
        <Say>Please press the input A.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

User A Input

```
@app.route("/user-A-input", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def UserAInput():
    """Handle key press from a user."""
    logger.debug('before considering user input A')
    strA = request.values.get('Digits', None)
    logger.debug('In side A| A:' + strA)
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    gather = Gather(action='/user-B-input')
    gather.say('Please press the input B.')
    resp.append(gather)
    return str(resp)
```

Then User B Input should work as you have it.

One last note, you currently are relying on the default timeout for `<Gather>` which means that the `Digits` will be submitted after the user stops typing for 5 seconds or if they press the `#` key. If you are expecting a certain number of inputs, you can use the [`numDigits` attribute of `<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-digits). You can also set other finishing keys with the [`finishOnKey` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-finish).

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I already tried what you have shared expecting that it would work, but to my surprise the phone would hang up every time it reached that line.

Comment: Did you return TwiML from the route? If you just returned an empty response then the phone would hang up.

Comment: If you’ve updated your code, can you edit your question to show what you have now, then I can take a look and try to help more.

Comment: I have shared an answer to my question. Check if that makes any sense.